# Implementing a fail-fast design with promises in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, fail-fast

I'm not sure if "fail-fast" is the best way to describe this methodology, but ever since I started to learn about programming I have always been taught to design functions like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    ... // do error-prone work here

    if (!allGood) {
        // Report error, cleanup and return immediately. Makes for cleaner,
        // clearer code where error-handling is easily seen at the top
        ...
        return;
    }

    // Success! Continue on with (potentially long and ugly) code that may distract from the error
}
```

As such, I'm trying to call a promisified function like so:

```
doSomethingAsync(param).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
}).then(() => {
    // Continue on with the rest of the code
});
```

But this gives me behaviour akin to the `finally` block of a classic `try...catch...finally` statement, i.e. the `then()` block will **always** be called, even after an error. Sometimes this is useful, but I rarely find myself needing such functionality (or `try...catch` statements in general, for that matter).

So in the interest of failing as quickly and clearly as possible, is there a way that I can make the second example above work in the way that I expect (i.e. `then()` is only executed if `catch()` wasn't, yet a single `catch()` will still catch all errors raised by `doSomethingAsync()`)?

Comment: Move your catch after the then, otherwise it restores the promise with whatever you return from the then. But now that if there's a promise, it's async, so returning values don't mean anything, unless you return a new promise from within the chain, or use async await to make it easier

Comment: @JuanMendes An issue with that is that the `.catch` will catch errors that occur inside the `.then`, whereas OP wants to catch errors only from `doSomethingAsync(param)` (and OP would rather have the catch logic close to the `doSomethingAsync` call, rather than after it and its `.then`)

Comment: @certain   If you don't want errors on the then to be passed to catch, you can pass a second parameter to then as the error callback

Comment: Here's an article explaining that behavior https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/347/javascript-promises-mastering-the-asynchronous/the-catch-method The OP should understand this

Comment: Errors in promises don't appear as error conditions that you will need to test for (like `if (!allGood)`, but they rather work like exceptions. Fail-fast is the default if you just don't do anything, just like when the "*error-prone work*" throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `async` and `await` instead of `.then`, you can effectively wait for the Promise to resolve (or reject), and if it rejects, return early:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    await doSomethingAsync(param);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  // Continue on with the rest of the code
})();
```

```js
const doSomethingAsync = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => Math.random() < 0.5 ? resolve() : reject('bad'));

(async () => {
  try {
    await doSomethingAsync();
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('continuing');
})();
```

That's what I'd prefer. You can also use the `.then(onResolve, onReject)` technique, though it's [usually not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289):

```
function onReject(err) {
  console.log(err);
};
doSomethingAsync(param).then(onResolve, onReject);
function onResolve() {
  // Continue on with the rest of the code
}
```

```js
const doSomethingAsync = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => Math.random() < 0.5 ? resolve() : reject('bad'));

function onReject(err) {
  console.log(err);
};
doSomethingAsync().then(onResolve, onReject);
function onResolve() {
  console.log('continuing');
}
```

This will have `onReject` *only* handle errors thrown by `doSomethingAsync(param)`. If your `onResolve` can throw inside its body as well, then you'll have to chain another `.catch` onto it (which will start to look a bit messy - it's usually nicer to catch errors in just one place)

Comment: @JuanMendes same goes for you :P Unless you were referring to the downvote on my question...since I don't know whether you or CertainPerformance downvoted me (but it seems as though it was you...no offence).

Comment: Wasn't me, but best to check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686

Comment: @kenny83 you are mistaken buddy. I actually upvoted  your question even though it's kind of unclear, but does show a problem you are trying to solve.  I tried to guide you in the right direction with the comments. Please don't assume, you know what that does

Comment: @kenny83 if you really want to check, check their rep history. That can at least prove if someone did not downvote you, look for a -1. :p. https://stackoverflow.com/users/227299/juan-mendes?tab=reputation

Comment: Downvote actions do not show up in other users' rep history (you can only see it for your own's)

Comment: @JuanMendes LOL fair enough mate, thanks for trying to help and for the upvote, and apologies for any offence taken; it certainly wasn't intended :-)

Comment: As CertainPerformance's link explains, it is much more pertinent to ask "*why* was my question/answer/comment downvoted", rather than "who is responsible for this abomination?!" LOL :P So if the downvoter sees this, please explain how I could better help myself and the community :-)